# r corrplot with clustering: default dissimilarity measure for correlation matrix

Tags: r, matrix, distance, hierarchical-clustering, r-corrplot

I used the R package `corrplot` to visualize the correlation matrix from my data. I involved the clustering of variables using the embedded option hclust. 
The invocation of the command was like this (plus various arrangements of titles, axes etc):

```
corrplot(Rbas,type="upper",order="hclust",method="ellipse")
```

But now I perform some analysis and visualizations using other packages, and the question arose about the compatibility of results. In particular, I have to repeat manually the clustering of the correlation matrix. But from the documentation to `corrplot` there is one obscure point: what dissimilarity measure was used in corrplot behind its reasonable defaults? Whether this is 1-|corr|, sqrt(1-corr^2), or anything else? In literature there are multiple choices, for example, as described in [this article](http://research.stowers.org/mcm/efg/R/Visualization/cor-cluster/index.htm)

*Update* to answer own question. I performed a guess trial, using the dissimilarity measure in the form 1-corr. That is I coded (Rbas is the correlation matrix):

```
dissim1<-1-Rbas
dist1<-as.dist(dissim1)
plot(hclust(dist1))
```

and recovered the ordering of variables, coinciding with the one suggested by default `corrplot` with `hclust` invocation. But it is not clear whether this is indeed their used mechanism and whether this will hold for any other matrix?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function used by `corrplot` to reorder variables is `corrMatOrder` (try `?corrMatOrder`). 
 It returns a single permutation vector.
When `order= "hclust"` is selected in `corrplot`, `corrMatOrder` invokes the `corrplot:::reorder_using_hclust` function:

```
function (corr, hclust.method) 
{
    hc <- hclust(as.dist(1 - corr), method = hclust.method)
    order.dendrogram(as.dendrogram(hc))
}
```

This function uses `1-corr` as dissimilarity measure.